# Using Google Map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I made a test a program which uses Google maps following a tutorial. I made everything like in tutorial, but my app crashes before even showing anything with message "Unfortunately HelloGoogleMaps has stopped". I tried to debug and it seems like it crashes even before entering to onCreate method. This is my code:

```
package ru.medinfo.HelloGoogleMaps;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class HelloGoogleMapsActivity extends MapActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Log after exception:

```
    01-27 16:22:34.195: W/dalvikvm(1038): Unable to resolve superclass of Lru/medinfo/HelloGoogleMaps/HelloGoogleMapsActivity; (3)
01-27 16:22:34.195: W/dalvikvm(1038): Link of class 'Lru/medinfo/HelloGoogleMaps/HelloGoogleMapsActivity;' failed
01-27 16:22:34.385: D/AndroidRuntime(1038): Shutting down VM
01-27 16:22:34.385: W/dalvikvm(1038): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ru.medinfo.HelloGoogleMaps/ru.medinfo.HelloGoogleMaps.HelloGoogleMapsActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ru.medinfo.HelloGoogleMaps.HelloGoogleMapsActivity
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ru.medinfo.HelloGoogleMaps.HelloGoogleMapsActivity
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
01-27 16:22:34.415: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     ... 11 more
01-27 16:22:34.465: W/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity ru.medinfo.HelloGoogleMaps/.HelloGoogleMapsActivity
01-27 16:22:34.488: W/WindowManager(87): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21010
01-27 16:22:35.001: W/ActivityManager(87): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41472d50 ru.medinfo.HelloGoogleMaps/.HelloGoogleMapsActivity}
01-27 16:22:35.295: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(87): setKernelCountSet(10044, 0) failed with errno -2
01-27 16:22:45.295: W/ActivityManager(87): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{41472d50 ru.medinfo.HelloGoogleMaps/.HelloGoogleMapsActivity}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.medinfo.HelloGoogleMaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name=".HelloGoogleMapsActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post logcat error stacktrace here.

Comment: please paste your MANIFEST too !!

Comment: done. added manifest too. I did all other tutorials well except for Google Maps. It uses MapActivity instead of Activity and I guess this is where the problem. It is a superclass of HelloGoogleMapsActivity. And Log says that this superclass is not resolved. I guess MapActivity is not found for some reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` inside your application's tag in your Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.medinfo.HelloGoogleMaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity android:name=".HelloGoogleMapsActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks's to everybody who helped, I was wasting about 4 hours on this bug. This is where the problem was. My stupid that I didn't follow the tutorial in this place "Open the AndroidManifest.xml file and add the following as a child of the <application> element:" At least I've learned how to solve such bugs. I understood that the problem was that MapActivity was not found, but why - this is where I stopped.

Comment: You're welcome. I think you're not the first one who faced this issue.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think order should be like this below.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Comment: It didn't work. I posted log. It says that ru.medinfo.HelloGoogleMaps.HelloGoogleMapsActivity class is not found? What may be a reason?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. But after moving 

within the  as explained in the earlier post; it worked.

As for the original exception; please try using the following code example:

```
    package com.example.hellogooglemaps;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.graphics.drawable.*;
    import com.google.android.maps.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class HelloGoogleMapsActivity extends MapActivity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
            mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

            List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.android);
            HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);
            OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hola, Mundo!", "I'm in Mexico City!");

            itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
            return false;
        }
    }
```